# How to match a number at the start of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to match a number at the start of each string:

```
1000_lang sorting_1 ghhgf_1002
1001_lang
100_abcdefg_sgdga_10001_321gg hjdshjdg
```

So, I will have numbers: `1000, 1001, 100` respectively. Basically, I want to match a number from a string until that number meets first underscore. But numbers can be any length, so if it is `12345_eyquyewuq_32136 df_1999` I need `12345`. Don't need any other numbers coming after the first underscore.

Comment: Are you searching many lines at once or one-by-one?

Comment: FYI you don't need a regex, you can obtain your desired result using parseInt function:
    `parseInt("1000_lang sorting_1 ghhgf_1002")` will produce number 1000


But with this approach you'll be accepting any character after the number, for example:
    `parseInt("1000whatever_1002")` will produce number 1000

Comment: please add a second parameter indicating that you want to use decimals `parseInt("1000_lang sorting_1 ghhgf_1002", 10)`   because in some navigators when you have a zero as the first char you'll find that `parseInt("039_blablab")` produces number 3 same as `parseInt("039_blablab", 8)` instead of number 39

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^\d+
```

Get all numbers from the start of the line up to the first non-number

```
str = "123456_wibble";
patt = /^\d+/;
result = str.match( patt);
```

result is an array of matches, so as long as there is 1 or more, you've found something

See [Mozilla Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Brackets around were wrong, you have edited it right now. Otherwise it was repeating itself.

Comment: Yes, confusing Perl and Javascipt :-D

Answer (score 2):

This answer is javascript only, but it may be usefull if you don't care about regex:

```
var str = "1000_lang sorting_1 ghhgf_1002";
var result = str.split("_")[0];
```

result will hold the first number.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this....

```
var str = '1000_lang sorting_1 ghhgf_1002',
    matches = str.match(/^\d+/)
console.log(matches)
```

Comment: You've just copied the accepted answer..... I realise you answered at the same time, but your answer was incorrect until your edit 10 minutes ago.